# Argparse File Output in Brackets and Single Quotes

Tags: python, string, input, output, argparse

Objective: To add a prefix or suffix to a string.

Problem: The output to the file is modified to include a [''] around the input. (ex: ['prefix']word, or word['suffix'])

Question: How do I remove the bracket and single quote around the input string?

Code:

```
    parser.add_argument('-p', dest='prefix', metavar='[Prefix]', nargs=1, help="Add a user     defined prefix")
    parser.add_argument('-s', dest='suffix', metavar='[Suffix]', nargs=1, help="Add a user     defined suffix")

#Adding a prefix to the string
    elif args.prefix:
        s = str(args.prefix)
        print s
        def addprefix(n):
            p = s + n
            args.outfile.write(p)
        myline = args.infile.readline()
        while myline:
            addprefix(myline)
            myline = args.infile.readline()
        args.infile.close

    #Adding a suffix to the string
    elif args.suffix:
        s = str(args.suffix)
        def addsuf(n):
            p = str(n.strip()+s+"\n")
            args.outfile.write(p)
        myline = args.infile.readline()
        while myline:
            addsuf(myline)
            myline = args.infile.readline()
        args.infile.close
```

Side Note: This is a snippet of code from the much larger program.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing the problem is `nargs=1`.  This tells argparse that you want to make a list.  Instead, remove the `nargs=1` bit and put in `action='store'`.  You may also want to specify a default.

```
parser.add_argument('-p', dest='prefix', 
                    metavar='[Prefix]',action='store',default='',
                    help="Add a user defined prefix")
```